# BootGridView Filter not working in Yii Framework

Tags: yii

I have tried to implement the sorting using BootGridView but it does not seem to work. Here is the line of code.

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BootGridView', array(
'id'=>'user-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'user_id',
    array('name'=>'user_type',
                'value'=>'User::getType($data->user_type)'),
    'username',
    array('header'=>'Name',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>  'CHtml::link($data->firstname." ".$data->lastname, array("view", "id"=>$data->id))'
    ),
            array('name' => 'status',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => '$data->status == 1 ? "Active" : CHtml::link("In Active", "javascript:void(0);", array("id" => "active_" . $data->id, "onClick"=>"js:activate($data->id)"))'
    ),
    /*
    'email',
    'dob',
    'profession',
    'hobby',
    'height',
    'weight',
    'weight_taken_on',
    'login_attempt',

    'registration_date',
    */
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.BootButtonColumn',
    ),
),
```

)); ?>

The code does not seem to sort the table as expected. What could be the possible problem in this. ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is configured in the data provider, not in the grid view. So you should look into the `search()` method of your model. You need something like this:

```
return new CActiveDataProvider('User',array(
    // ...
    'sort' => array(
        'attributes' => array(
            'name',
            'email',
            // ...
```

Have a look at [`CSort`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort) and especially the [`attributes`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort#attributes-detail) property there to learn more about sort options you can use here.

Comment: Still I could not get exact to my solution. Would please be specific to my problem. Thanks

Comment: You should show how you have configured sorting in the `search()` method of your model.

Comment: I have already implemented search() function. The problem is searching and filtering works on the column from same table but dont work on columns from another table.

Comment: You still haven't shown your sort setup. If you want to sort by a related column, then the `name` in your gridview must be in dot format, e.g. `profile.url`, if `profile` is the name of the relation. And you must add `profile.url` to your sort configuration.